# difference between two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find difference between two dataframe and the resulting df should return the rows matching the first dataframe. Since id's 6,7 was not there in df2 so the count value is as it is.

**My Two Dataframes**

[image]

**Resulting Dataframe:**

[image]

Comment: please paste the data in the question instead of providing screenshot, helps us get your data directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align `DataFrame`s by `id` columns, add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for `id` only by `df1.id`:

```
df = (df1.set_index('id')
        .sub(df2.set_index('id'), fill_value=0)
        .reindex(df1['id'])
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  count
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3      0
3   4      0
4   5      0
5   6      9
6   7      4
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join, then subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with extracting `count_` column by [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
df['count'] = df['count'].sub(df.pop('count_'), fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df)
   id  count
0   1      0
1   2      0
2   3      0
3   4      0
4   5      0
5   6      9
6   7      4
```

**Setup**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                    'count':[3,5,6,7,2,9,4]})

print (df1)
   id  count
0   1      3
1   2      5
2   3      6
3   4      7
4   5      2
5   6      9
6   7      4

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,8,9],
                    'count':[3,5,6,7,2,4,2]})

print (df2)
   id  count
0   1      3
1   2      5
2   3      6
3   4      7
4   5      2
5   8      4
6   9      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
temp = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='id').fillna(0)
temp['count'] = temp['count_x'] - temp['count_y']
temp[['id', 'count']]

   id  count
0   1    0.0
1   2    0.0
2   3    0.0
3   4    0.0
4   5    0.0
5   6    9.0
6   7    4.0
```