# Pandas difference two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, left-join, inner-join

I have two frames that share a column 'company' .
I want to check which entries from DF2 are NOT in DF1, taking only the 'company' column into account.
Right now I do it through a loop like this:

```
Unique = []
for index, row in DF2['Email'].iterrows():
    if row['Email'] not in DF2['Email'].values:
        Unique.append(row)
unique_df = pd.DataFrame(Unique)
```

I feel there should be a .join method that does this but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't have a lot of experience with sql and am still a relative beginner with pandas and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you have any example data you can share?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041663/difference-between-two-dataframes-in-pandas

Comment: Search for "ANTI-JOIN" in the [linked duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)